# Simulate a custom function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, simulation

I'd like to simulate the following function:

```
l(t) = mu + Σ (1 + (t-t_i)/alpha)^(beta)
```

I wrote the function as follow:

```
function[l] = custom(m,t,H,par) 
k = length(H);
n = length(t);
l = par.mu(m)*ones(n,1);
  for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:k
    h = H{j};
    h = h(h < t(i));
    if ~isempty(h)
       d = t(i) - h;
       l(i) = l(i) + sum((1+ (d/par.alpha(m,j)))^ par.beta(m,j));
    end   
  end
end
```

Now, how can I simulate this function for t=1000, par.mu= 0.5, par.alpha = 0.1,  par.beta  = 0.3?

I have the following code for simulation of this function but it's not efficient...How can I make it better?

```
function[h] = simcustom(t,par)
h = -log(rand)/par.mu;
if h < t
   do5 = 1;
   i = 0;
   j = 0;
   k = 0;
   n = 1;
   while true
    if do5;
     k = k + 1;
     Lstar(k) = custom(1,h(n),{h},par);            %#ok
  end
  j = j + 1;
  U(j) = rand;                                         %#ok
  i = i + 1;
  u(i) = -log(U(j))/Lstar(k);                          %#ok
  if i == 1
     Tstar(i) = u(i);                                  %#ok
  else
     Tstar(i) = Tstar(i-1) + u(i);
  end   
  if Tstar(i) > t
     h = {h};
     break
  end   
  j = j + 1;
  U(j) = rand;
  if U(j) <= custom(1,Tstar(i),{h},par)/Lstar(k)
     n = n + 1;
     h = [h Tstar(i)];
     do5 = true;
  else
     k = k + 1;
     Lstar(k) = custom(1,Tstar(i),{h},par);
     do5 = false;
  end
 end   
  else
   h = {[]};
  end
```

And here is the application:

```
par2.mu    = 0.5;
par2.alpha = 0.1;
par2.beta  = 0.3;
t = 1000;

h2 = simcustom(t,par2);
```

Comment: What is `t` and what is `t(i)`?

Comment: @David t is a parameter (maximum time of simulation) and ti is the parameter that I want to simulate (random times between 0 to t)

Comment: In your code you only have 1 `t` though?

Comment: I want to simulate t_i which have the maximum of 1000

Comment: Start by preallocating and don't use the suppress warnings, usually they serve their purpose. DON'T use `while true`, just don't. For sake of nice coding, organize your indents (has nothing to do with perf). Now a more important part: use `profile on`, then `profile viewer`. Then you should be able to find the weak spots.